# Upgrading CentOS-5.11 kernel

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, veracrypt

How would I go about upgrading the CentOS-5.11 kernel from 2.6.18-398 to 2.6.24 (or newer)? I'm trying to setup automated VeraCrypt Encrypted Volume on NAS devices. Currently there are known bugs with any kernel version older then 2.6.24. Also I can't upgrade to CentOS-6 for this particular environment.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS/RHEL 5 kernels are not just vanilla 2.6.18; they contain innumerable backports of features and bug fixes from newer kernels. They're pinned to a specific kernel release number to maintain ABI compatibility.

You could certainly download and build [a newer 2.6 kernel](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/), but it will lack all of the extra stuff provided with the CentOS/RHEL kernel, which may pose other compatibility problems with the rest of the system.

I suggest the following:

1. Verify whether Veracrypt is truly certified for use on CentOS/RHEL 5. If it is, and there are known bugs, Veracrypt may have a workaround.
2. Check the changelog for 2.6.18-419, as the bugs you're worried about may indeed be fixed in it.

In the end, @steve is correct. CentOS 5 is EOL, and the proper path forward is to upgrade. Unless the 2.6.18-419 kernel contains fixes for the bugs you're worried about, I submit that what you're being asked to do is unreasonable.

Comment: Yea i convinced management we better wait until our OS upgrades to CentOS-7 are done rather then haphazardly updating kernel

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://vault.centos.org/5.11/updates/x86_64/RPMS/ suggests the most recent update (25-Feb-2017) is kernel-2.6.18-419.

Furthermore, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#End-of-support_schedule suggests CentOS 5 doesn't get updates any more.

You need to rethink this and upgrade to an OS that's actually supported/maintained.

Comment: I would love too just cant cause we are going to be upgrading to CentOS 7 in couple of months but management wants to use encrypted NAS devices ASAP. I'm stuck. So theirs no way to use Non-supported Kernel on older CentOS-5.11 ?